# fixating rotation around a dynamicly moving plain

Tags: animation, rigging

I have the following situation

[image]

The entire object is rigid. The bottom plate can rotate around the blue(z) axis. The torso should be rotation with it and the arm should rotate around the side of the torso.

Whenever I put the objects as parent of bone they will work in their default positions. However if I turn the base around 45° and then the arm the rotation will not be around the torso. Instead the arm detaches a bit.

Here is a video of what I mean:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tkyDClpAtaM

I just want the bones to only rotate 90° to the normal of the location surface

Is there a way I can fix my rotation to a plain (torsoside) with its two axis as references?

Comment: I am not sure I follow.... Click the animation in this file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yu7etzj0ydk384u/NOT_SURE.blend?dl=0 and what should the horizontal arm bone do?

Comment: I added a video showing what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click <kbd>r</kbd> for rotation you can limit the rotation on **world axis** by hitting ( <kbd>x</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> or <kbd>z</kbd>) or on **local axis** ( <kbd>x</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> or <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>z</kbd>)

first place the bones in a good way

- rotate around the local axis
  or
- select the bone in pose mode
- in **Bone Constraints** add **Limit rotation** constraint
- setup the constraint according to your needs (in this case see the image )
- now the bone will only rotate around the desired axis

Bones setup:

[image]

Bone constraint :

[image]

result :

[image]

Comment: OK that is what I wanted. It seems my mistake was placing my bones my way. I used limited rotation constrains on bones before and they glitched to because my bones are not set that way. I am gonna test this now, thx

Comment: You did limit the first and the third bone right? Because bone001 is normally the second which confused me a little

Comment: @Wandang yes exactly , the screenshot is from another setup